# vector subtract I am using python 3.5

Tags: python

```
def vector_subtract(v, w):          
    """subtracts two vectors componentwise"""         
    return [v_i - w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w)]
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Comment: What are you asking? Edit: please format your code so it is easily viewed.

Comment: Evidently you are trying to subtract dictionaries.

Comment: I am getting error in my code, TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for -: dict and dict

Comment: def vector_subtract(v, w): 
              return [v_1 - w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(vow)]

Comment: Please pride a minimal example of the vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JJ_Shakur, Here is a possible solution for a generic vector class:

```
import numpy as np

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.elms = np.array(args)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        self.elms.resize(other.elms.shape) if len(self.elms) < len(other.elms) \
                                           else other.elms.resize(self.elms.shape)
        return Vector(*(self.elms - other.elms))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.elms[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.elms)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.elms)

'''
The main function
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1 = Vector(0.6,0.3,0.5,1.0)
    v2 = Vector(1.0,1.0,0.5)

    print('sub: {}'.format(v1 - v2))
```

Comment: thank you so Much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I think this will work, so if I need to do same thing with Addition and Multiplication can I use this class too,

Comment: yes, i'll link you to more examples: https://github.com/aidanmelen/computer_graphics/blob/master/hw-6/vector.py

Comment: @ Aidan I am facing new issue now, I was trying to sue some of your code plus mine, I am trying to create vector sum and mean here  is  the code   def vector_sum(vectors):
        return reduce(Vector.__add__, vectors)
    def saclar(c, v):
        return [c * v_i for v_i in v]
    
            # this isn't right if you don't from __future__ import division
    def mean(vectors):
            """compute the vector whose i-th element is the mean of the \i-th elements of the input vectors"""
            n = len(vectors)
            return Vector.saclar(1/n, Vector.vector_sum(vectors))

Comment: the error code
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'elms'

Comment: please update your original question, with formatted code.

Comment: @ Aidan, I don't know how to edit the original question I am very new to the system, also I can't put my question in this beautiful template I will appreciated if you could help me on this, I am trying to crate a mean and sum vector. thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how to subtract vectors.

```
vector1 = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
vector2 = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]

def subVector(vec1, vec2):
    return [[vec2[0] - vec1[0], vec2[1] - vec1[1]] for vec1, vec2 in zip(vec1, vec2)] 

print(subVector(vector1, vector2))
```

Which gives:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

I think that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am not looking in general how to subtract vector, I need to iterate and zip through the process for loop!!

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a custom subtract function, I would suggest using a magic method. For example, this is how the int and str object's override the **__add__()** function...

```
# this is how the int object does it...
a = 1
b = 2

# a + b = 3

# and this is how the str object does it...
c = "hello"
d = "world"

# c + d = "helloworld"
```

Notice that in both cases, the same operator is used, but with different results, depending on how the object overwrites the **add**() magic method.

You could leverage the power of magic methods by creating a Vector class and override the **__sub__()** magic method.

For example, here is a simple Vec3 class:

```
class Vec3():
    def __init__(x, y, z):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z

    """
    Can be called simply like v - w, if v and w are Vector's.
    :param other:  Another Vector to be subracted to self.
    :return: The difference of the two vectors.
    """
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y, self.z - other.z)
```

This way, we can create many Vec3 instances...

```
vec3_a = Vec3(4,5,6)
vec3_b = Vec3(1,2,3)
```

and subtract them by using the "-" operator

```
vec3_diff = vec3_a - vec3_b
```

Comment: To begin with, I’ll frequently need to add two vectors. Vectors add or subtact componentwise. This
means that if two vectors v and w are the same length, their sum is just the vector whose
first element is v[0] + w[0], whose second element is v[1] + w[1], and so on. (If they’re
not the same length, then we’re not allowed to add them.)
For example, adding the vectors [1, 2] and [2, 1] results in [1 + 2, 2 + 1] or [3, 3],. I am not sure how your magic three will helping me on case

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own Vector class

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


    def print_axes(self):
        return self.x, self.y, self.z


    def sub(self, vec_s):
        self.x -= vec_s.x
        self.y -= vec_s.y
        self.z -= vec_s.z
```

In the Main file:

```
robot1 = Vector(float(1.0), float(2.0), float(3.0))
robot2 = Vector(float(2.0), float(2.0), float(2.0))

robot1.sub(robot2)

print(robot1.print_axes())
```

Result in the Console:

```
(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)          
(-1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you, for the next time I would be careful much more!